# How to finally straighten out my perl installation on Mac OS X 9.2?

Tags: macos, perl

I've been really struggling with Perl on Mac OS X 10.9.2.

I've had this iMac since 10.5, and I believe I've screwed it up as a result of things I was forced to do because of the changing conditions of Mac OS X vs. Perl.
Now I have all kinds of oddball problems like the below where a module (in this case `Algorithm::Permute`) seems to be screwed up (wrong architecture?!?!).
This program just says `use Data::Nested;`:

```
% ./geo_test.pl 
Can't load '/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4//darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Algorithm/Permute/Permute.bundle' for module Algorithm::Permute: dlopen(/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4//darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Algorithm/Permute/Permute.bundle, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4//darwin-thread-multi-2level/auto/Algorithm/Permute/Permute.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture at /System/Library/Perl/5.16/darwin-thread-multi-2level/DynaLoader.pm line 194.
 at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4//Data/Nested.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4//Data/Nested.pm line 38.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4//Data/Nested.pm line 38.
Compilation failed in require at ./geo_test.pl line 8.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./geo_test.pl line 8.
%
```

But yet, everything else says it's installed correctly, like so:

```
cpan[5]> cpan[4]> i /Algorithm::Permute/
Module id = Algorithm::Permute
    CPAN_USERID  EDPRATOMO (Edwin Pratomo <epratomo@acm.org>)
    CPAN_VERSION 0.12
    CPAN_FILE    E/ED/EDPRATOMO/Algorithm-Permute-0.12.tar.gz
    MANPAGE      Algorithm::Permute - Handy and fast permutation with object oriented interface
    INST_FILE    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/Algorithm/Permute.pm
    INST_VERSION 0.12


cpan[5]>
```

I've repeatedly done `sudo cpan/install CPAN/reload cpan/install <module>`, I've tried `cpanm`, I've tried everything I can think of, but it continues to behave bizarrely.  Is there any way I can wipe Perl off my system and start over?

Comment: So you have two builds of Perl. `geo_perl.pl` is using your 5.12.4 install. `cpan` is probably tied to your 5.16 install. Get that path from the shebang of `geo_perl.pl`. Say it's `/foo/bar/perl`. Use `/foo/bar/perl -MCPAN -e shell` to run `cpan` to install the module for that Perl.

Comment: Re "Is there any way I can wipe perl off my system and start over?" Yes, you can do exactly that. Delete your second install, but leave your system `perl` untouched. Then use `perlbrew` to install the desired version of Perl locally.

Comment: Hmmm, very interesting, that explains a lot.  The perl in my path, /opt/local/bin/perl, is 5.12.4, the one in the shebang, /usr/bin/perl, is 5.16.2.  Can you give me a bit more idea of how to delete my second install?  Simply by /bin/rm?  Thanks - Ed

Comment: Easiest solution: Fix your path.

Comment: cpan is killing me.  I installed 5.18.2 with perlbrew, fixed my path to include only that perl, ran that cpan with that perl and installed a couple of modules.  It tells you *nothing* about what it does, whether it succeeds or fails or where it's putting the modules or anything else.  There are *no* files with today's date in the perlbrew tree, it's as if the 'cpan i' command did nothing at all.  And needless to say, the test program finds no modules: % head -1 geo_test.pl 
#!/Users/edwardbrowne/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/bin/perl
% ./geo_test.pl 
Can't locate Geo/Coder/Google.pm in @INC

Comment: What's the version given by `perl -v`? What's the output of `set | grep '^perlbrew ()'`? [If blank, don't bother answering the following questions] What's the output of `perlbrew list`? [If there's no "*", do `perlbrew switch 5.18.2` or whatever] What's the output of `cpan Geo::Code::Google`?

Comment: % perlbrew switch perl-5.18.2

A sub-shell is launched with perl-5.18.2 as the activated perl. Run 'exit' to finish it.

bash-3.2$ set | grep '^perlbrew ()'
bash-3.2$ which perl
/Users/edward/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.18.2/bin/perl
bash-3.2$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 18, subversion 2 (v5.18.2) built for darwin-2level

Copyright 1987-2013, Larry Wall (...)

bash-3.2$

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52217/discussion-between-edb-and-ikegami)